# converting mongo shell query into Bson list for aggregate framework when using mongo async java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to add group for id and createTimeStamp.
I have below dependency in my project.

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongodb-driver-async</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```html
db.repocollection.aggregate(
    {$match:{
 $and: [ 
 {updateTimeStamp :null},
 {id : {$in:["G9A0103C17D36D46F508E566131A3C62","E9A0103C17D36D46F508E566131A3C62"]}}
 ]}},
 {$group:{_id:"$id",id : { $first: '$id' }, "createTimeStamp": {$min:"$createTimeStamp"}}},
 {$sort:{'createTimeStamp':1}}
)
```

```html
return asList(
        match(and(eq("updateTimeStamp", null), in("id", ids))),
        ));
```